# Purpose of the [function], [method], [variable], etc. tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Can someone please explain to me the use for the tags [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method) and [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable). I don't feel like they add anything to the question, as these concepts are very basic. I'm not necessarily saying that they should be removed, but it seems to me as useless as adding a tag like [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming).

**Edit:**

Also what are the advantages of having [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method) be a separate tag from [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) if in its description it states that they are synonyms.

Comment: Just like you guesses, they have no purpose.

Comment: The only use I can see for those is for sub-1500 users to post the first question about a new-to-SO language so that a 1500+ can create the appropriate tag.

Comment: @tepples Should a specific tag be created like new-language or something? Not something completely vague like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[They should all be 'nuked' and blacklisted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/173497) If they're useless, they should be removed.

We're all experts on those topics.