# Are we over-[extending] our tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

I don't think it's a *stretch* to say the [extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extending) tag goes *too far*. Perhaps you will *reach* the same conclusion as I have.

There's no usage guidance or wiki. There are 288 questions with this tag, which only has 2 watchers.  I could only find one person who has answered more than one question with this tag, and they answered three.  As a standalone tag, it seems useless compared to the tags meant to represent the concept it apparently represents.

A review of the tagged posts indicates the overwhelming majority are referencing inheritance by extending classes, functions, models, etc. which would be much better categorized with either the 1,444 questions associated with the [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extend) keyword, or the 110,412 other questions in the [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) tag. There are a few randomly tagged questions unrelated to inheritance or functionality.

The tag doesn't seem to fail all the burnination criteria, as [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) and use of the [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extend) keyword is definitely on topic for the site.  As a stand-alone tag, however, it seems rather useless, and I think most questions would better fit under one of the existing tags.

Proposal (updated from comments):

1. Remove the tag from the handful of questions that don't deal with inheritance
2. Make [extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extending) a synonym of [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance)

---

As the comments have tended toward possible burnination, I'll evaluate those criteria here.  I still favor a cleanup/disambiguation.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does, mostly describe extending functionality.  However, it is ambiguous as there are multiple ways of extending things, including inheritance, extensible programming, and others. Most use `extend` or `extends` keywords.

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Specific implementation is on topic.  The generic category of `extending` is probably more of a "design" discussion which would be off topic.

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. The posts generally stand on their own asking the specifics of it.  Given the low number of watchers it's unlikely the tag is useful for meaningful additions to, or exclusions from, searches.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.  Extending object-oriented classes (inheritance) is distinctly different than extending functions and methods, extending schema, and other applications.

Comment: It might be a *stretch* But I think this would be useful and can be achievable if we are ```extending``` our reach far enough.

Comment: (2) is wrong, [tag:extending] functionality of non-OOP objects have nothing to do with [tag:inheritance].

Comment: What exactly [tag:extend] is supposed to cover isn't defined to begin with. The extend tag wiki as it currently stands is crap. Far as I know, it is a keyword in multiple languages and that's what the tag should be for. I'd start by fixing that tag wiki, then decide how to go from there.

Comment: I would vote for removing the tag.

Comment: extend/ing have different meaning depending on the language, so the correct use of this tag would be in conjunction with other tags, ie: [extending][php][class] . I don't see how the tag extend/ing could have a stand-alone limited definition.

Comment: @Lundin how about going the opposite way, remove the tag and see who screams.

Comment: @Braiam It makes perfect sense to have a tag for language keywords. If it should be different tags for different languages, well that's another story.

Comment: @Lundin prepare to have thousands of tags, [tag:startwith], [tag:now], [tag:datetime], [tag:getutcdate], [tag:UTC_TIMESTAMP], [tag:etc] there's no need for such absurd. [We already discussed this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306970/792066) but it seems that the collective has short memory.

Comment: If [tag:extending] has nothing to do with [tag:inheritance], then it *at least* has something to do with [tag:extend]. Let's just synonymize those two, which are clearly related. Whether we should burn [tag:extend] is a different proposal & conversation.

Comment: We definitely need an "etc" tag :D I can't wait to answer the first one!

Comment: Regarding your edit, is this now a case for burnination?

Comment: @zcoop98 as I indicated in the edit "I still favor a cleanup/disambiguation." but figured I'd offer that additional evaluation for commenters or answerers if they would rather go that route.

Comment: General note: Let's please remain civil in the comments, and not attack other users who have a different opinion.

Answer (score 12):

IMO, the [extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extending) tag should be removed.

There aren't any questions with only that tag (though I counted 4 or 5 with just one other tag).  There are no 'experts' in the extending topic — only one of the top 30 answerers has answered more than one question (and they've answered two); only two of the top 30 askers has asked more than one question (three and two — and one might ask them why they used the tag).  Some of the questions probably need close votes ([How does extending a programming language work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699971/how-does-extending-a-programming-language-work) for example).  It's the "clean up of the questions" part that will be painful.

Answer (score 6):

Even if some of the possible meanings of the tag are on-topic, that doesn't necessarily mean that it shouldn't be burninated. This *could* refer to things that are off-topic (even if it's not intrinsically off-topic).

Also, it's still very ambiguous, and it's adding no value to the site.

I say we burninate it.